# How to query a post using advanced custom fields?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Okay, don't know whether a constructive post or not but would be so helpful if someone could help me with this.

I am learning WordPress development and am a total beginner with advanced custom fields.

I have setup a custom field with radio buttons to chose from the post category.,

see,

```
tech : Tech
news : News
sports : Sports
city : City
```

So whenever I post something, I can choose the category, but I don't know how to query the post with the WordPress loop,

How can I do this? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you so much for your time and sorry for my English.

- Anything you could say about ACF would be helpful, I have browsed the api documentation but I cant start from a point. Thank You so much. GBU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get custom field of post that you created from `ACF` plugin:-

```
$field = get_field($field_name, $post_id, $format_value);
```

[See Documents here](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field/)...